# Баги Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, xfce

Долгое время пользовался Xubuntu 17.10 и меня в ней всё полностью устраивало, но вот с выходом 18.04 столкнулся с парой мелких неприятностей. У меня сейчас стоят обе этих системы, использующие общий радел home и проблемы возникают только в 18.04, так что дело не в локальных пользовательских настройках, а в самой системе.

Во-первых, сразу после установки я полез устанавливать драйвер видеокарты (nvidia). В 17.10 последняя версия - 384, с ней у меня нет никаких проблем. В 18.04 версия 390 и она вроде бы рабочая, но после установки `ForceCompositionPipeline = On` (эта опция решает проблемы с тирингом), система намертво зависает при первом запуске и чтобы она отвисла, приходится заблокировать сессию и снова разблокировать (командой `xflock4`). И тут возникает вторая странность.

Экран блокировки имеет не стандартное разрешение (1920х1080), а какое-то другое. Я долго гуглил как поменять разрешение при блокировке и нашёл только статьи о смене разрешения этого экрана при начальной загрузке системы, но в том-то и дело, что баг происходит исключительно в случае блокировки экрана!

В общем, проблему с зависанием я решил установкой более старого драйвера (340), но разрешение экрана блокировки по-прежнему кошмарное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой ответ пусть и не отвечает на вопрос "как исправить проблему в xubuntu", но может кому-то будет полезно: Обе эти проблемы с версией драйвера nvidia 390 актуальны для дистрибутивов xubuntu и antergos, причём в antergos всё гораздо хуже - после установки драйвера система вообще не грузится! Однако каким-то волшебным образом этот же драйвер в manjaro из коробки работает идеально, так что если у кого-то будут подобные проблемы - ставьте manjaro.